Improving equation looks
I am relatively new to working with LaTeX and I'm trying to improve looks of a few equations in my document. The equations are pretty basic, e.g.:
\[
\varepsilon^'_i = \frac{M_i^'}{F_i \times K^'}
\]

But somehow the end result looks amateurish in terms of letter formatting, prime placing and visibility, etc. I would be glad to get some tips on how to make these simple equations to look more professional...

Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide MWE from \documentclass to \end{document}

Never  x^' just x' you are making primes too small and too high

Try to remove the ^ before the prime. Maybe that is the only thing you need to fix.

Removing "^" seems a definite improvment, thnx!

Some suggestions (the first one is actually an imperative, not a suggestion):

write ' rather than ^'. No exceptions.

either replace \times with \cdot or  \, (thinspace) or just omit entirely

optional: To ensure that the prime symbols to the right of the M_i term in the numerator and the K term in the denominator are placed at the same height, replace K' with K_{\vphantom{i}}'.



\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\[
\varepsilon_i' = \frac{M_i'}{F_i \, K_{\vphantom{i}}'}
\]
\end{document}

